# Why is HC-SR501 PIR motion Sensor always on?

Tags: pi-3, python, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to make an alarm system but the motion sensor is always on as soon as the script is run. I've posted a question about a different problem i was having with this project so it'll confusing to edit it all to discuss these other problems wont it?

**Inputs**
button
motion sensor
keypad

**Outputs**
leds,
buzzer,
oled display(haven't got to his yet)

**Configuration**

**button** - ground > 10k > 10k > gpio,
**buzzer** - 5v > NPN 8050 > 5k > gpio> ground,
**leds** - ground > 220k > gpio,
**motion sensor** - 5v > gpio > ground

when the motion sensor is triggered or the button is pressed all outputs should turn on. if the button is pressed again, outputs should turn off.

**Current problems**

1) it seems the PIR motion sensor is always giving input because it just turns the alarm on and stays on. The button works fine. it will turn off the alarm once the motion sensor triggers it but then the motion sensor wont trigger it again.

2) The key pad is printing the digit but wont turn off the alarm.

**Code**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import matrixKeyboard

alarm_end = time.time() + 60 * 3  # alarm_ends after 3 mintues

Leds = [37, 35, 33, 31]
buzz = 13
motionSensor = 12
button = 29

def setup():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(Leds, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(buzz, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(motionSensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
    GPIO.setup(button, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)


current_state = 0
btnState = 1

def alarm():
    GPIO.output(Leds,True)
    GPIO.output(buzz,True)

def alarmOff():
    GPIO.output(Leds,False)
    GPIO.output(buzz,False)
    control  

def swMotion():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    current_state = GPIO.input(motionSensor)
    if current_state == 1:
      alarm()
      time.sleep(4) # wait 4 seconds for PIR to reset. 


def swState(ev=None):
    global btnState
    btnState = not btnState
    GPIO.output(Leds, btnState)  # switch led status(on-->off; off-->on)
    GPIO.output(buzz, btnState)
    if btnState == 1:
        print ('led on...')
    else:
        print ('...led off')       

def Keypads():
    key = matrixKeyboard.main()
    if key == 1:
        alarmOff()


def loop():
    try:
        GPIO.add_event_detect(button, GPIO.FALLING, callback=swState, bouncetime=200) # wait for falling   
        swMotion()
        Keypads()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        destroy()


def destroy():
    GPIO.output(Leds, False)
    GPIO.output(buzz, False)
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':     #Program start from here
    setup()
    while True:
        loop()
```

**Matrix Keypad script**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

class keypad():
    # CONSTANTS   
    KEYPAD = [
    [1,2,3,"A"],
    [4,5,6,"B"],
    [7,8,9,"C"],
    ["*",0,"#","D"]
    ]
    ROW = [18,22,24,26]
    COLUMN = [32,36,38,40]

    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

    def getKey(self):

        # Set all columns as output low
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.LOW)

        # Set all rows as input
        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
            GPIO.setup(self.ROW[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

        # Scan rows for pushed key/button
        # A valid key press should set "rowVal"  between 0 and 3.
        rowVal = -1
        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
            tmpRead = GPIO.input(self.ROW[i])
            if tmpRead == 0:
                rowVal = i

        # if rowVal is not 0 thru 3 then no button was pressed and we can exit
        if rowVal < 0 or rowVal > 3:
            self.exit()
            return

        # Convert columns to input
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

        # Switch the i-th row found from scan to output
        GPIO.setup(self.ROW[rowVal], GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(self.ROW[rowVal], GPIO.HIGH)

        # Scan columns for still-pushed key/button
        # A valid key press should set "colVal"  between 0 and 2.
        colVal = -1
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
            tmpRead = GPIO.input(self.COLUMN[j])
            if tmpRead == 1:
                colVal=j

        # if colVal is not 0 thru 2 then no button was pressed and we can exit
        if colVal < 0 or colVal > 3:
            self.exit()
            return

        # Return the value of the key pressed
        self.exit()
        return self.KEYPAD[rowVal][colVal]

    def exit(self):
        # Reinitialize all rows and columns as input at exit
        for i in range(len(self.ROW)):
                GPIO.setup(self.ROW[i], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) 
        for j in range(len(self.COLUMN)):
                GPIO.setup(self.COLUMN[j], GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def main():
    kp =  keypad()
    digit = None
    while digit == None:
        digit = kp.getKey()
    while digit != None:
        print (digit)
        digit = kp.getKey()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

**Edit**

Ok. So it seems the motion sensor turns on even when gpio is not plugged in. 
It must be connected to 5v and ground so what am I suppose to do if I cant stop it being high? a resistor?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

***Question***

> PIR motion sensor always on and stays on. Why?

---

***Answer***

*Part 1 - HC SR501 Analog Sensor - **Not Recommended***

This analog sensor is difficult to adjust sensitivity and delay time using the two little trim potentiometers.  It is also be easility be interferenced by noises.

[image: sensor spec]

[image: sensor test]

I googled to find that analog PIR sensors such as HC SR-501 have a noise problem.

[PIR Module False Positives](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67402/pir-module-false-positivesq)

Possible reasons include: forgot pullup/down resistor, too noisy (from microwave oven, induction cooker for example, cable too long, cable not shielded, power noise (due to power hungry BlueTooh, Wifi, solution is turn them off or heavily by pass/decouple Rpi USB)

After more experimentation, I concluded that analog sensors are not reliable, or too many false positive, or always on.  A quick fix is switch to digital sensor such as AM312.

---

*Part 2 - AM312 Digital Sensor - **Highly Recommended***

There is no sensitivity and time delay adjustment needed.   The factory default settings are:

> Delay time: 2 seconds;
>
> Blocking time: 2 seconds;
>
> Triggering method: repeatable

I found this digital PIR sensor very newbit friendly.

[image: AM312 digital sensor]

---

***References***

(1) [Introduction to HC-SR501 A complete step by step tutorial on Introduction to HC-SR501](https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2019/01/introduction-to-hc-sr501.html)

(2) [TaoBao HC-SR501 PIR Sensor Module - ¥3.23](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad43nX1A5&id=563241533003)

(3) [TaoBao DC 12V Water Proof Smart PIR Sensor Module With Switch - ¥12.80](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad43nX1A5&id=589366692547)

(4) [TaoBao AM312 PIR Sensor ¥5.28](https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z1r.7974869.0.0.269c3ad43nX1A5&id=574891236513)

(5) [AliExpress AM312 DC 2.7 to 12V Mini IR Pyroelectric Infrared PIR Motion Human Sensor Automatic Detector Module  - US$1.29](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Mini-IR-Pyroelectric-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Human-Sensor-Automatic-Detector-Module-AM312-Sensor-DC-2-7/32843951990.html?spm=a2g0w.10010108.1000016.1.67717e2a7tU0pg&isOrigTitle=true)

(6) [Pyroelectric Infrared Radial Sensor AM312 (DSP, Schmidtt) Manual - NanYang SenBa](http://www.image.micros.com.pl/_dane_techniczne_auto/cz%20am312.pdf)

(7) [PIR Sensor Description and Technical Details - AdaFruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/189)

(8) [PIR Sensor Tutorial - AdaFruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Pyroelectric Infrared Radial Sensor AM312 Specification*

> 1. Working voltage: DC 2.7-12V;
> 2. Delay time: 2 seconds;
> 3. Blocking time: 2 seconds;
> 4. Triggering method: repeatable
> 5. Sensing range: ≤ 100 degrees cone angle, 3-5 meters; (according to the specific lens)
> 6. Operating temperature: -20 - +60 °

*Features*

> 1. Anti-interference enhancement, the internal use of digital signal
>      processing, direct high-low output.
> 2. Repeatable triggering mode: If a cat moves in the sensing range during the delay period, and output is high, output will remain high
>      until delay time after the cast has left, ie, the sensing module will
>      automatically delay after detecting an activity of the cat, with the
>      time of the last activity as the starting point of the delay time.

---

[image: am312 pir 1]

[image: am312 pir 2]

---

*Appendix B - PIR devices*

[image: pir toys]

---

Answer (score 1):

Please **double-check the wiring on the sensor**. It looks like some HC-SR501 modules have pins GND-OUT-VCC, and some have VCC-OUT-GND.

At least on mine I had to remove the plastic cover with the Fresnel lens to see the labels next to the pins (it slides in and out quite easily).

**If you plug the ground to VCC and the 5V input to GND like I did, then the signal output stays constantly at about 5V.**